# Unable to see Home, My Subscriptions, Site Settings - RS2008 R2 on a domain

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am trying to get security on Reporting services set up. I have installed  reporting services with all the defaults and I was able to create and publish a report. Using the link `[http://server/reports]` I was able to view that report. Bearing in mind that i am in the domain administrators group.

I then asked a non domain admin user to review the report but they got the message: •   The permissions granted to user `'DOMAIN_ABC\username'` are insufficient for performing this operation. `(rsAccessDenied)`

It then dawned on me that I would need to set up security by assigning the 'Browser' role to  `DOMAIN_ABC\Domain` Users.

At that point I realized that I had no way of interfacing with the security side of things as none of the Home, My Subscriptions, Site Settings tabs were displaying (as is the case with a 2005 RS deployment we have). Thus began my search for how to get the 'admin' view into the environment to enable security and access. I have thus far been unsuccessful so far, I have tried running IE as the 'Administrator', added the server to my 'Trusted' sites list. Checked the RS config file, set the Service Account to 'Local Service' but still no joy. Does anyone know what I may try?

Thanks in Advance,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

You can not view the admin settings unless u got that permission.
Only Report manager administrator can create roles  and users  from report manager url [http://localhost/Reports/] then go to site settings ----> security,----> new role assignment.

If the user in system Administration group then only he can view the site settings option in the home page, If the user is on other group like content manager /System user then he can not view the site settings option.

You need to first add the user in the System Administrator group.then he can view all these settings.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Sunil,

Thanks for the answer - I have blown away that install and am starting again. I will let you know how I go.

Jonathan